# How to crawl images from Amazon EC2 to S3 without saving to EC2 local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a brunch of images in urls to be downloaded on Amazon EC2. I wanted to 1) download them, 2) rename it with a certain rule 3) save to S3. I know I could do it locally on EC2 and sync the folder to S3, but is there a good way that I could download and rename those images directly to S3?

Comment: No, but you could remove the need for EC2 by using something like Lambda.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the reply! Could you provide a quick example or pointer for this?

Comment: I can't speak for it, but Googling "lambda download to s3" got me https://spock.rocks/tech/2016/04/22/lambda-downloading-to-s3.html.